# Setting a timer using user input, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I'm very new to programming.

For a school project, I'm trying to set a setTimeout(); function using input from the user.
Here is my code:

```
let header = document.getElementById('header');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
let response1 = document.getElementById('response1');

function playSound() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio")
    x.play()
  }, 3000); //input.value?? or 1000 * input.value??
}
```

Normally, if i want to access the user's input within the input box I would type input.value.
However, the setTimeout function does not recognize input.value as a parameter that can be set to be used as a countdown. I don't know what to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want the user to enter the delay?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting (console output)?

Comment: I was not getting an error message within the console. The function would execute instantly as if no timeout was present. I.E. my playSound function would execute instantly regardless of the number from the input.value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `setTimeout` function does not recognize `input.value` as a parameter that can be set to be used as a countdown

It does recognize it. If you are encountering an error, then most likely your input is a text input, in which case you have to convert its value to a number before using it in `setTimeout`:

```
let header = document.getElementById('header');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
let response1 = document.getElementById('response1');

function playSound() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio")
    x.play()
  }, Number(input.value));
}
```

If the value entered is in seconds, use `input.value * 1000`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `setTimeout` automatically converts the second parameter into number.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much, I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: @dmitryguzeev no it doesn't. It just regards any string entered as 1, so `setTimeout(foo, "1000")` is the same as `setTimeout(foo, 1)`

Comment: @WaisKamal I tested it on both latest Firefox and Chrome releases. If you pass "5000" as a second parameter, it waits 5 seconds.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right. No idea how it worked for the OP though :)

Answer (score 1):

To execute setInterval dynamically, you need to call function instead of the input text:

1. Create a function `startInterval`
2. Call function `onChangeInterval` in event of the input text with the value of the input

---

```
<script>
    var intervalId;
    
    function startInterval(_interval) {    
        intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        }, _interval);
    }
    
    function onChangeInterval (interval) {
        interval -= 100;
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        startInterval(interval);
    }
</script>
```